# Is there a reason an older Macbook won't run Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I needed Mountain Lion because some of the newer software of Apple, such as Xcode, requires Mountain Lion, but besides the iMac 27 I have, sometimes I need to go on trips and need to bring a white Macbook that I bought near end of 2007.

It is indeed a very decent Core 2 Duo notebook (besides the screen dimming a little after so many years because it is not LED type), with an Intel graphics card that is capable of playing all videos and Flash games I tried, but wonder, this Macbook can't install Mountain Lion and so I need to buy either a new Macbook Air for about $1200 or a Macbook Pro for $1800 to $2200 (depending on whether it is Retina).  Is there a reason why Mountain Lion can't be installed on this notebook?  Since it is to run Xcode mainly, graphics card performance is not needed if that may be a reason -- or for other reasons?

Comment: Would "Back to my Mac" to get back to your home base be an option?

Comment: but I need to do programming on the road... such as ski trips for a few days...

Comment: Then you need a new laptop or stay with an older version of XCode.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it has to do with **32-bit** graphics cards drivers, as they do not support **64-bit EFI**.

While **Mountain Lion** is compatible with any Mac capable of running a 64-bit kernel, the kernel does not support loading 32-bit kernel extensions. So, since the **early 64-bit** Macs use **32-bit** drivers, Mountain Lion won't load them.

You can find out if your computer has a 32-bit or 64-bit EFI by running the command: `ioreg -l -p IODeviceTree | grep firmware-abi`

It will return either **<"EFI64">** or **<"EFI32">**.

Comment: so it would only be possible if a 64-bit driver is written for the old graphics card?  (or what if it is just a mapper (just a facade))?

Comment: If you manage to upgrade your graphics card, then, *theoretically*, it should work. Perhaps with a facade you'll *cheat* the System into letting you install it, but I will cause a bunch of issues, afterwards.